# "instance variable hold values that must be referenced by more than one method"?

Tags: java, instance-variables

I read carefully the explanations about instance variable at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_variable_types.htm

I found "instance variable hold values that must be referenced by more than one method" is very confusing. I think it is supposed to be >= 1.

Comment: It's not only confusing, but plain wrong. You can perfectly have an instance variable not used by any method or constructor. You *typically* use them in one or several methods of the class, but it **must not** be referenced by any method or constructor.

Comment: It doesn't have to be referenced by anything. I have no clue why that statement is there. If you have a private member variable that is not referenced by any member in your class, it will generate a warning though. You can however set your IDE/compiler to generate errors for warnings. Then that statement *"must be referenced"* would apply.